# Declaring primitive type properties

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, primitive-types

I want to declare properties with `int`s and `bool`s, for example:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) bool signOutgoingFax;
```

The error I get is:

> property 'signOutgoingFax' with 'retain' attribute must be of object type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not retain `BOOL` `int` or `float`. Simply use

```
@property(nonatomic) bool signOutgoingFax;
```

The point here is that the variable is declared as "BOOL", not "BOOL *" (this would be a pointer), and hence you should not use `retain`.

Comment: you have been very helpful last few days. Thanks for being a positive help.

Comment: This is correct, but remember that `bool` and `BOOL` are two separate types. The latter having been around since before `bool` existed, but was desired.

Comment: what about `assign` directive?